# showing the Non property of java bean in Display tag

Tags: jsp, displaytag, struts2

let's say.. I have the following java bean.

**Case1: (Student Bean)**

```
Integer id;

String name;

ArrayList<String> subjectNameList;
```

and using the above case1 structure, I can use to display in display tag like that.

```
<displaytag:table class="displayTable" id="studentList" name="studentist">
<displaytag:column property="id" title="id"/>
<displaytag:column property="name" title="name"/>
<displaytag:column property="subjectNameList" title="subjectNameList"/>
</displaytag:table>
```

But now due to the changes, student bean becomes like that.

**Case2: (Student Bean)**

```
 Integer id;

 String name;

 ArrayList<Integer> subjectIdList;
```

So, in the display tag table, I know I can no longer display the subject name list directly because that is no longer property of student bean.

My question is.. **Is there any way to show the subject name list like in Case1 in display tag ( which can be get via in Action class and pass to display tag for each student bean) ? Because in Case2, list changes to ID (integer) list.
I want to maintain the same look and feel in jsp page of display tag.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend the [TableDecorator](http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/displaytag/apidocs/org/displaytag/decorator/TableDecorator.html) to handle Case 2 like Case 1. More info about [Decorators](http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/1.2/tut_decorators.html)

**Sample TableDecorator implementation for above case:**

```
public class StudentBeanDecorator extends TableDecorator {

    public String subjectNames()
    {
        StudentBean studentBean = (StudentBean)getCurrentRowObject();
        ArrayList<Integer> subjectIdList = studentBean.getSubjectIdList();

        // make a service call or as you like
        ArrayList<String> subjectNameList = studentService.getSubjectNameList(subjectIdList);

        // format the data as you want; here for sample, just doing comma separated string
        return Arrays.toString(subjectNameList.toArray());;
    }
}
```

**And mapping decorator to display:table tag**

```
<displaytag:table class="displayTable" id="studentList" name="studentist" decorator="com.sample.student.StudentBeanDecorator">
    <displaytag:column property="id" title="id"/>
    <displaytag:column property="name" title="name"/>
    <displaytag:column property="subjectNames" title="subjectNames"/>
</displaytag:table>
```